# How do I replace this text in a file from the command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, perl, command-line, sed

I have a proxy config file which has the following line:

```
Allow 212.21.3.44
```

I'd like to replace that IP address portion with my new IP address when it changes. It would probably be easier to just use the line number when searching for it &ndash I don't think that config file will change at all other than that particular setting.

How can I do it from the command line with something like like Perl, sed, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use sed to change a specific line number, you could use:

`sed -i '<line number> s/Allow .*$/Allow <new ip>/g' <filename>`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/my.new.ip.here/' file.txt
```

The `-i` flag will change the file in place (depends on your distro/flavor of *nix - works on Ubuntu for me).

Comment: And on most Linux box's you can add a '-i' option to `sed` to have it make the change to that file directly.

Comment: seems dangerous to bulk change all ip addresses in the file to the new one, when the poster mentions one specific line

Comment: evilclown, good catch! think i might go with Brandon's solution below for that reason

Comment: @evilclown good point. I mistakenly assumed that it was the only line in the file.

Answer (score 1):

in case line number does change

```
sed -i '/Allow/s/Allow .*$/Allow <new ip>/' <filename>
```